# SSIS Lookup on data being imported

Tags: ssis

This is a classic does the record exist then update otherwise insert scenario. The dataflow process I am following is as follows:

1. OLE DB: return list of fields one of which is a calculated hashvalue on a number of the fields in the dataset
2. Lookup: See if the row has changed by comparing the hashvalue and another key field(allows duplicates) against the latest record in the target table for that key field.
3. If matches update the record, if no match then insert.

The problem I am having is that one of the records that I would match against is in the dataset I am importing and not in the target table. Therefore I always geta NO MATCH result. If I delete the row causing the error in the target table then re-run the import I do get a MATCH.

I have tried turning off the cache for the lookup with no success. Suffice to say I have searched for the answer with no luck. **HELP**

Comment: What is the error being caused?  Why is a row being imported that doesn't exist in the target getting a NO MATCH and therefore being inserted a problem?

Comment: Yeah I totally don't understand the problem here.   What do you mean "a record that you would match against is in the dataset and not the target table"?   So, match what against what?   What row in the target table are you talking about deleting, when you just said it doesn't exist?   Probably some example data, on both sides of the lookup, would help.

Comment: Check out Merge.  It should handle this situation.

Comment: Assume fields `ID|Value` Source data looks like 3|abc;4|bcd;3|cde. If inserted in that order, the desire is to have 2 rows in the database: 4|bcd and 3|cde. The challenge being that neither 3 ID had been written to the database and are inserted in the same batch thus violating the unique constraint?